# How to map Tsql User Defined Function using Fluent NHibernate?

Tags: sql, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, user-defined-functions

How to map Tsql User Defined Function using Fluent NHibernate? I have found a solution which works with hbm.

http://ayende.com/blog/1720/using-sql-functions-in-nhibernate

But I am using ClassMaps.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that `<sql-query>` is not yet implemented in FluentNHibernate. There's an [open issue](https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/issues/62) on GitHub.

However, you can mix both fluent mappings and .hbm mappings using FluentNHibernate configuration. Here's an example for that: http://www.dotnetguy.co.uk/post/2009/11/01/stored-procedures-with-fluent-nhibernate/

Something like this:

```
Fluently.Configure()
    .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008.ConnectionString(c => c.Is("...")))
    .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<SessionFactory>())
    .Mappings(m => m.HbmMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<SessionFactory>())
    .BuildSessionFactory();
```